# loop through each input in any given formId

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

how can i loop through each input of any form by form id

```
$("form#add-librarian-form :input[type!='button']").each(function () {
    var input = $(this);
    var formGroup = input.parents('.form-group');

    if (isEmptyInput(input)) {
        removeSuccessClasses(formGroup);
        removeErrorMessage(formGroup);
        addErrorClasses(formGroup);
        validForm = false;
    } else {
        validForm = validForm & validateInput(input, formGroup);
    }
});
return validForm;
```

this statement *$("form"+**formId**+":input[type!='button']").each* dont work !!

Comment: You forgot a `#` before your ID and a space after : `$("form#"+formId+" :input[type!='button']")`

Comment: thanks , its work now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more legal way to iterate through form elements (sorry for vanilla JS :) )

```
var form = document.getElementById("yourAwesomeForm")
for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
    var input = form.elements[i]

    // this is unnecessary, if you want all form elements to be processed
    if (input.getAttribute("name")) {
        /* do something with input */
    }
}
```